# Error on simple four link mechanism simulation with modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm trying to implement a 4 link mechanism and the model I've put together is shown here:

Revolute1 has a speed of 5 rad/s. All bars are 0.05 m in diameter. World settings are the default and you can see the bar vectors on the picture. Nothing else is changed.

When I try to run the simulation I get these errors on OpenModelica:

> [1] 10:29:43 Symbolic Error
>   [Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts: 238:5-238:62]: Model is structurally singular, error found sorting equations
>
> [2] 10:33:25 Translation Error
>   Internal error Transformation Module PFPlusExt index Reduction Method Pantelides failed!

What am I doing wrong? It seems pretty straight-forward. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the conditions in the upper right of the linked diagram fulfilled? In my experience, singular models are often either because of redundant equations or somehow incompatible conditions at start. Another possibility is that your equation system cannot be fulfilled, e.g. if the lenghts of your bars are wrong so that they can't be physically connected, I guess.

Comment: @Christoph Unless I misunderstood how the "r" vector of the bars work I fullfilled it.
From what I see, "r" is always relative to the position of point frame_a right?
In that case you can see in the model that my ABCD points are set like this: {0, 0, 0},  {0, 2, 0}, {4, 3, 0}, {5, 0, 0} which gives AB = 2, BC = sqrt(17), CD = sqrt(10) and AD = 5

Aside from the "r" vector and the diameter do I have to put any other parameter for the bars?

Comment: I can't help you there, I never worked with mechanical components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace one of the `Revolute` joints with a `RevolutePlanarLoopConstraint`. Why? Citing the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/libraries/Modelica/Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.RevolutePlanarLoopConstraint.html):

> If a planar loop is present, e.g., consisting of 4 revolute joints
>   where the joint axes are all parallel to each other, then there is no
>   unique mathematical solution if all revolute joints are modelled with
>   Joints.Revolute and the symbolic algorithms will fail. The reason is
>   that, e.g., the cut-forces in the revolute joints perpendicular to the
>   planar loop are not uniquely defined when 3-dim. descriptions of
>   revolute joints are used

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the required usage of `Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Joints.RevolutePlanarLoopConstraint` for the planar four bar linkage also the model topology needs to be adapted, asuming `bar2` is fixed to `world`. See the example model [Planar4Bar](https://gist.github.com/dietmarw/1460972583c1d82458cbb80a185197fb).